# Can i instantiation my superclass by using my subclass?

Tags: objective-c, subclass, superclass, objectinstantiation

`deck` is my superclass and `playingCardDeck` is my subclass of deck.
i found that i can i instantiation my superclass by using my subclass which confuse me a lot.
Can you tell me about this.Which `init` method will be used and any other features about this.thanks in advance.

```
#import "XYZViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
@interface XYZViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipLabel;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger flipCount;
@property (nonatomic) Deck *deck;
@end

@implementation XYZViewController
- (Deck *)deck
{
    if (!_deck) {
        _deck=[self createDeck];
    }
    return _deck;
}
- (Deck *)createDeck
{
    return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc]init];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be surprising at all. This is quite normal OOP (it's formally called the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). An object of type `Animal` can accept an object of type `Dog`. But you can only call `Animal` methods on it.

In your example, the `init` for `PlayingCardDeck` will be executed. Anyone who accesses `deck` will only be able to call methods that are defined on `Deck`, but the implementation will be the one provided by `PlayingCardDeck`.

Comment: what about the instance variables that the subclass hold? Can `deck` have access to them? Thanks a lot.By the way, can you recommend me a book on oc which talks about the these kind of thing(class subclass,inherit) in details.I'm new to the oc(even new to the OOP language).thanks a lot.Really thanks:)

Comment: This isn't really Objective-C; this is just object oriented programming (OOP). The instance will of have all of its properties. But any caller who has a `Deck`-typed variable won't be able to access anything that isn't part of `Deck`. There are a many good introductions to OOP (most of the ideas are equivalent across OOP languages). http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ (or just search for "introduction to oop")